# Sum SQL Fields Together For total result

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to Sum a number of fields within a SQL Database.
The fields are called week1 to week 13 as they store results for each week.
I have this at the moment however it is not outputting anything, any help would be appreciated. Cheers

```
<?php
            if ($resultsRows == 0){
            echo '<p> No results have been listed for you yet. </p>';
            }
            if ($resultsRows > 0){              
            $qrytotalresult = "SELECT SUM(week1 + week2 + week3 + week4 + week5 + week6 + week7 + week8 + week9 + week10 + week11 + week12 + week13) FROM results WHERE username = '$username'";
            $TotalResult = mysql_query($qrytotalresult);
            return $TotalResult;

            }
        ?>
```

Comment: SQL is not the only problem here - mysql_query does not return the value. You have to use mysql_fetch_array() to get it.

Comment: $result = mysql_fetch_array($query);
   echo $result; 

I have now added that to grab and print - Except now it prints the word Array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 SELECT SUM(week1) + SUM(week2) + SUM(week3) + SUM(week4) + SUM(week5) +  
        SUM(week6) + SUM(week7) + SUM(week8) + SUM(week9) + SUM(week10) +  
        SUM(week11) + SUM(week12) + SUM(week13) 
 FROM results 
 WHERE username = '$username' 
 group by username
```

This should do the trick.
*(Assumption: There are multiple rows for each user. If each user has only one row than sum function and group by clause can be omitted)*

Comment: <?php
  
   $overallresult = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(week1) + SUM(week2) + SUM(week3) + SUM(week4) + SUM(week5) +                  
 SUM(week6) + SUM(week7) + SUM(week8) + SUM(week9) + SUM(week10) +    SUM(week11) + 
 SUM(week12) + SUM(week13) 
 FROM results 
  WHERE username = '$username'");

   return $overallresult;
   
   
  ?>

I now have this although nothing is being shown when I Return and if I echo I get Resource ID #4

Comment: As a matter of fact, `GROUP BY` can be omitted either way, because you are only retrieving rows for a single user.

Comment: what would be causing it not to be printed out?

Comment: because mysql_query outputs the query result, and you should fetch it with `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysql_fetch_row` etc.

Comment: $result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
   echo $result;
   
I have added that and it prints out "Array"

Answer (score 2):

`SUM()` is an aggregate function, for adding rows.  To add columns simply use `+`, though be aware that if any of the columns is NULL you might not get the result you expected.

```
SELECT IFNULL(week1, 0) + IFNULL(week2, 0) + IFNULL(week3, 0) AS sumweeks //etc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT week1 + week2 + week3 + week4 + week5 + week6 + week7 + week8 + week9 + 
week10 + week11 + week12 + week13 as sumweeks 
FROM results WHERE username = '$username'
```

would be enough